# How do I manipulate state from a child component using props and spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, spread-syntax

I am passing down props.key and props.expansion, whose data types are string and an object respectively.

In the if statement, the JS engine throws an error for the second argument that is after the spread operators(props.key: true), with the error message saying a comma is required.
I do not see any error in the code.

Please point out and suggest a solution for the arguments(particularly the second argument) of props.selectExpansion in the if statements.

```
const Expansion = (props) => {

return (
    // unique props.key is the expansion name
    <div className={props.key} onClick={() => {
    // only alters the expansionList state by changing the expansion name corresponding to props.key
        
    // change the boolean value of expansion on expansionList
        if(!props.expansion[props.key]) {
            props.selectExpansion(...props.expansion, props.key: true)
        } else {
            props.selectExpansion(...props.expansion, props.key: false)
        }
    }}>
        
      <h1>Expansion</h1>
    </div>
    );
}
 
export default Expansion;
```

Comment: I think you are intended to pass an object as the second argument but you are directly passing it. Wrap it in curly braces. {[props.key]: true}

Comment: Hi, my intention is to set the state using selectExpansion. The state has 24 key/value pairs, so I am using the spread syntax. Then i use props.key:true (or false) to change just one key/value pair. It is not working. 
update) your solution worked!

Comment: Are you sure `props.key` is even accessible in the component? React has a couple ***very special*** props, `key`, and `ref`, that are not passed on to children components. In other words, they are inaccessible from a child component. If `props.key` is accessible somehow then you need to pass an object, with `props.key` as a dynamic property name, i.e. `props.selectExpansion({ ...props.expansion, [props.key]: true })`.

Comment: @DrewReese I will definitely have to check that too after I solve this problem. Thanks for pointing out; you saved me a question

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what is the `props.expansion` anyway if you want to change something inside of that object, code could be changed to the following:

```js
// change the boolean value of expansion on expansionList
if(!props.expansion[props.key]) {
    props.selectExpansion({...props.expansion, [props.key]: true})
} else {
    props.selectExpansion({...props.expansion, [props.key]: false})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding, I think we need to see the parent component but I think you are trying to set the state as it is just with the updated key value. Hence you need to wrap the params in an object.

```js
const Expansion = (props) => {

return (
    // unique props.key is the expansion name
    <div className={props.key} onClick={() => {
    // only alters the expansionList state by changing the expansion name corresponding to props.key
        
    // change the boolean value of expansion on expansionList
        if(!props.expansion[props.key]) {
            props.selectExpansion({...props.expansion, props.key: true})
        } else {
            props.selectExpansion({...props.expansion, props.key: false})
        }
    }}>
        
      <h1>Expansion</h1>
    </div>
    );
}
 
export default Expansion;
```

See I have used this

```
props.selectExpansion({...props.expansion, props.key: true})
```

Instead of

```
props.selectExpansion(...props.expansion, props.key: true)
```

Earlier you were passing 2 params to the setState(selectExpansion) function.

Comment: very silly mistake I made, thank you!

Comment: Also, Is this key attribute part of react props or a separate attribute? Are you able to access it? This may still not work. 

You'll have to do something like 

props.selectExpansion({...props.expansion, [props.key]: true}). 

Only if the key is accessible and not a react prop.